# Creating DistinctBy using Expression trees

Tags: c#, linq, expression-trees

I wanted to create a method extending `IQueryable` where a user can specify in a string a property name by which he wants to distinct a collection. I want to use a logic with a `HashSet`.
I basically want to emulate this code:

```
HashSet<TResult> set = new HashSet<TResult>();

foreach(var item in source)
{
    var selectedValue = selector(item);

    if (set.Add(selectedValue))
        yield return item;
}
```

using expression trees.

This is where i got so far:

```
private Expression AssembleDistinctBlockExpression (IQueryable queryable, string propertyName)
    {
        var propInfo = queryable.ElementType.GetProperty(propertyName);
        if ( propInfo == null )
            throw new ArgumentException();

        var loopVar = Expression.Parameter(queryable.ElementType, "");
        var selectedValue = Expression.Variable(propInfo.PropertyType, "selectedValue");

        var returnListType = typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(queryable.ElementType);
        var returnListVar = Expression.Variable(returnListType, "return");
        var returnListAssign = Expression.Assign(returnListVar, Expression.Constant(Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(queryable.ElementType))));
        var hashSetType = typeof(HashSet<>).MakeGenericType(propInfo.PropertyType);
        var hashSetVar = Expression.Variable(hashSetType, "set");
        var hashSetAssign = Expression.Assign(hashSetVar, Expression.Constant(Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(HashSet<>).MakeGenericType(propInfo.PropertyType))));

        var enumeratorVar = Expression.Variable(typeof(IEnumerator<>).MakeGenericType(queryable.ElementType), "enumerator");
        var getEnumeratorCall = Expression.Call(queryable.Expression, queryable.GetType().GetTypeInfo().GetDeclaredMethod("GetEnumerator"));
        var enumeratorAssign = Expression.Assign(enumeratorVar, getEnumeratorCall);

        var moveNextCall = Expression.Call(enumeratorVar, typeof(IEnumerator).GetMethod("MoveNext"));

        var breakLabel = Expression.Label("loopBreak");

        var loopBlock = Expression.Block(
            new [] { enumeratorVar, hashSetVar, returnListVar },
            enumeratorAssign,
            returnListAssign,
            hashSetAssign,
            Expression.TryFinally(
                Expression.Block(
                    Expression.Loop(
                        Expression.IfThenElse(
                        Expression.Equal(moveNextCall, Expression.Constant(true)),
                        Expression.Block(
                            new[] { loopVar },
                            Expression.Assign(loopVar, Expression.Property(enumeratorVar, "Current")),
                            Expression.Assign(selectedValue, Expression.MakeMemberAccess(loopVar, propInfo)),
                            Expression.IfThen(
                                Expression.Call(typeof(HashSet<>), "Add", new Type[] { propInfo.PropertyType }, hashSetVar, selectedValue),
                                Expression.Call(typeof(List<>), "Add", new Type[] { queryable.ElementType }, returnListVar, loopVar)
                                )
                            ),
                        Expression.Break(breakLabel)
                        ),
                    breakLabel
                    ),
                    Expression.Return(breakLabel, returnListVar)
                ),
                Expression.Block(
                    Expression.Call(enumeratorVar, typeof(IDisposable).GetMethod("Dispose"))
                )
            )
        );
        return loopBlock;
    }
```

I get an exception when `Expression.Block` is called for a variable `loopBlock` which goes like this:

> No method 'Add' exists on type 'System.Collections.Generic.HashSet`1[T]'.

Comment: I think that you are creating the HashSet with the wrong type. You are creating with with the type of `item`, not the type of `selectedValue`. By the way, it is really hard to work with your code. Try to provide a code sample that we can compile and run.

Comment: It's not that unfortunately :( Okay, i'll edit the code soon
EDIT: It should me easily testable now

Comment: It's probably easier to just generate the selector delegate instead of the whole distinct method. Fyi.

Comment: It's pointless to create an `IQueryable` implementation that can only ever be used to evaluate `IQueryable` objects that are actually just `IEnumerable` objects.  If you're going to do that you might as well just make the method accept an `IEnumerable` to begin with, rather than accepting IQueryables that won't actually work properly with this method.

Comment: Why are you actually doing this?

Comment: to learn expression trees and figure out how they work :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`Expression.Call` method overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb351107(v=vs.110).aspx) that you are using is for static methods.

Quoting from the reference above:

> Creates a MethodCallExpression that represents a call to a static (Shared in Visual Basic) method by calling the appropriate factory method.

What you need to do is to use [an overload of that method that is for calling instance methods](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb336138(v=vs.110).aspx).

Here is how the relevant part of your code would look like:

```
Expression.IfThen(
    Expression.Call(hashSetVar, "Add", new Type[] { }, selectedValue),
    Expression.Call(returnListVar, "Add", new Type[] { }, loopVar))
```

Notice how now we pass the instance (expression) that we need to invoke in the first parameter of `Expression.Call`.

Please note also that we pass an empty type parameter list. The reason for this is that the `Add` method in this class does not have any type parameters. The type parameter `T` in `HashSet<T>` and `List<T>` is defined on the class level, not on the method level.

You would need to specify the type parameters only if they are defined on the method itself like this:

```
void SomeMethod<T1>(...
```